# Scroll programmatically to the bottom of an expandablelistview with big content in last item

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of an expandablelistview programmatically. Every other thread in SO points to either:

```
var groupPosition = listView.ExpandableListAdapter.GroupCount - 1;
var childCount = (listView.ExpandableListAdapter as MyAdapter).GetChildrenCount (groupPosition);
listView.SetSelectedChild (groupPosition, childCount, false);
```

or:

```
var groupPosition = listView.ExpandableListAdapter.GroupCount - 1;
listView.SetSelectedGroup (groupPosition);
```

These work great if your list items aren't taller than the height of the screen, however in my scenario the data in the last item of the expandablelistview can sometimes be taller than the screen, especially in landscape mode.

I've tried using listView.ScrollTo, however it creates a big area of white space at the bottom. Any input on how to scroll literally to the bottom of the expandablelistview, not just to the last group or child?

Comment: why don't you try scrolling using xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding these attributes to `xml`having `ListView`

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

Or set them programmatically,

```
listView.StackFromBottom = true;
listView.TranscriptMode = TranscriptMode.AlwaysScroll;
listView.TranscriptMode = TranscriptMode.Normal;
```

Comment: That makes it auto-scroll to the bottom on load, I only want it to scroll to the bottom in one programmatic case.

Comment: Your suggestion led me to the solution, which is to set those attributes programmatically when I need to scroll to the bottom then immediately remove them so they don't affect other behavior.

Comment: listView.StackFromBottom = true;
listView.TranscriptMode = TranscriptMode.AlwaysScroll;
listView.TranscriptMode = TranscriptMode.Normal;

Comment: If you include the code I mentioned in your answer then I'll accept answer. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Justin yes, so it could be helpful to others too, see I have edited my answer.